Выбор БД / СУБД для управления конструкторской документацией
У нас небольшое производство, храним всю конструкторскую документацию в сетевых папках на сервере / в бумажных архивах.
Мы хотим (я хочу) создать приложение / простую СУБД для управления документацией, и перед нами встал выбор инструментов.
База данных будет хранить документы древовидной структуры (сборочные чертежи).
Пример: есть Сборочный чертеж СБ_0 (какое-то оборудование), который состоит из вложенных сборочных чертежей СБ_01, СБ_02, СБ_03 и деталей Д_01, Д_02, Д_03, а каждый СБ в свою очередь может включать другие СБ и детали и так примерно 5-6 уровней вложенности.
Потом появляется СБ_1, он состоит из СБ_11, СБ_12, СБ_03 и деталей Д_11, Д_02, Д_03.
Получается, что каждый потомок может входить в разные ветки (выделил курсивом).
Т.е. при проектировании условно серийного оборудования, мы заимствуем узлы из предыдущих версий. И если мы вносим изменения в какую-то деталь, то нам важно отслеживать это изменение в каждом СБ, в который эта деталь входит.
Сейчас это выглядит как бесконтрольная и бессистемная прогулка по папкам в поисках чертежей, и если наши конструкторы что-то меняют, нам тяжело это отслеживать.
Я представляю это так: таблица для сборочных чертежей, таблица для деталей и таблица для связи многие-ко-многим между сборочными и деталями.
Где можно воссоздать древовидное отображение данных? Я немного знаком с Python и PostgreSQL, но может есть более специфичные решения? 
На картинке плюс-минус идеал: слева - древовидная структура, справа - информация о выбранном элементе. Меня сейчас интересует больше управление такой древовидной структурой документов. Вопросы интеграции с CAD / CAM системами сейчас не рассматриваем.
Вопрос о покупке специализированного софта у нас не стоит.

Ну так то любая реляционная БД такие данные и связи может хранить, вопрос именно в клиенте/GUI, который эту базу будет отрисовывать в нужном вам виде. Выглядит вообще не сложно.

@CrazyElf в целом, я могу смотреть в сторону Python + PostgreSQL?

Я бы взял готовый продукт. Скажем, у нас используется для этих целей Союз-PLM.

@Akina я выделил для себя несколько российских вендоров (Союз, Топ системы, Аскон, Интермех), наверное покупка готового продукта это действительно единственный адекватный вариант...

@Irking Смотреть можете, но не думаю, что на питоне удобно писать интерфейсы. Хотя можно конечно на tkinter или QT что-то такое налабать. Лучше наверное готовое взять.

Красивая картинка. Python + PostgreSQL подойдёт, без сомнения, но это далеко не главное. Хочется обратить внимание на два момента:

Доступ (как минимум на запись) к хранилищу чертежей должен быть только через интерфейс приложения, иначе всё это ни к чему.
Интеграция с CAD/CAM. Без этого никуда, и это несложно. Наверняка найдутся библиотеки для Питона. Но это поможет избежать дублирования данных. Например, спецификация сборочного чертежа. Либо она является источником информации, либо БД, а спецификация в этом случае должна генерироваться автоматически из БД.

Интеграция с CAD/CAM сделает создание спецификаций автоматическим процессом.

Да, Вы правы, тут слишком много подводных камней. Создание системы своими силами скорее всего сейчас непосильная задача для нас

Нет, вполне посильная. Начните. За несколько дней уже можно что-то работающее сделать. Потом постепенно добавлять функционал.
